# Unsigned reg subtraction in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have some troubles with unsigned reg subtraction in Verilog.

The following Verilog code is designed for a 4-bit ALU :

```
module p2(in_1,in_2,s,out);
input [3:0]in_1,in_2;
input [1:0]s;
output [4:0]out;
reg [4:0]out;
parameter ADD=2'b00;
parameter SUBTRACT=2'b01;
parameter AND=2'b10;
parameter OR=2'b11;

always @(in_1,in_2,s)
begin
    case (s)
        ADD:        out=in_1+in_2;
        SUBTRACT:   out=in_1-in_2;
        AND:        out={1'b0,(in_1&in_2)};
        OR:         out={1'b0,(in_1|in_2)};
    endcase
end
endmodule
```

**Problem1:**
For the case `in_1=4'b0000`,`in_2=4'b0001`,`s=2'b01`

I think `in_1-in_2` should be: `0000-0001=0000+(1110+1)=1111`

So `1111` should be zero-extended(due to unsigned subtraction) to `01111`,

then is assigned to `out=5'b01111`

However,the correct result show that `out=5'b11111`

Why?

**Problem2:**
For the case `in_1=4'b0001`,`in_2=4'b0001`,`s=2'b01`

I think `in_1-in_2` should be: `0001-0001=0001+(1110+1)=10000`

Then it is assigned to `out=5'b10000`

However,the correct result show that `out=5'b00000`

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **physical hardware**, a register contains only the binary data, signed unsigned are of just a matter of human interpretations.

Here, in your case, it is a matter of **Expression width evaluation**. Referring to SystemVerilog [LRM 1800-2012](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/02/25/get-your-ieee-1800/), section 11.6:

> The number of bits of an expression is determined by the operands and the context.
>
> SystemVerilog uses the bit length of the operands to determine how many bits to use while evaluating an expression.
>
> The bit length rules are given in 11.6.1. In the case of the addition operator, the bit length of the
>   **largest** **operand**, including the **left-hand side** of an assignment, shall be used.
>
> The number of bits of an expression (known as the size of the expression) shall be determined by the
>   operands involved in the expression and the context in which the expression is given.

Referring to example given in LRM:

```
logic [15:0] a, b; // 16-bit variable
logic [15:0] sumA;
logic [16:0] sumB; // 17-bit variable

sumA = a + b;  // expression evaluates using 16 bits
sumB = a + b;  // expression evaluates using 17 bits
```

The mistake you are making here is calculating 2's complement for 4-bits and expecting a 5-bit output. While the language uses **maximum bit length** in an expression to do the same.

Here, `out` is a **5-bit** register. So the 2's complement of minuend is taken for **five bits**. That is, 2's complement of `4'b0001` is `5'b11111`. Adding this to an extension of `4'b0000` as `5'b00000`, we get `5'b11111`. Henceforth your first problem's result.

Similar, comments applies for your Problem-2, Adding `5'b11111` to `5'b00001` results in `5'b00000`.

For more information about signed subtraction, refer to [this](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523210/subtracting-a-large-unsigned-binary-number-from-a-smaller-one) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162329/verilog-signed-vs-unsigned-samples-and-first) links.